# Combine yesod-auth backend with SPA front end

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a simple web app that was previously using servant that I decided to switch over to yesod to power the JSON API. My hope was to use the standard [`yesod-auth`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.6.8/docs/Yesod-Auth.html) tools for authentication and authorization on this API, but I can't figure out how I can use that authentication scheme without also using yesod to serve my entire site.

For instance, my site runs at
http://localhost:8080 for the JS frontend
http://localhost:3000 for the yesod backend.

Using the yesod plugins, I get an auto-generated page for logins at http://localhost:3000/auth/login. This is great and has a convenient "Login with Oauth2.0 partner" button that will set the session cookie; however, that cookie is only good for the localhost:3000 site. If I embed the login link in my frontend and redirect to the frontend after authentication, I lose my session cookie.

Is there something simple I'm missing with this? Or does `yesod-auth` only work with server-side rendered web pages?

Comment: Example of yesod with SPA: https://github.com/psibi/yesod-rest
Note that I use React as the frontend. The code is tailored for pre 1.6 versions of Yesod. But similar concepts still apply.

Comment: @Sibi Thanks for the example, but this doesn't seem to run them as two separate servers as best I can tell? It looks like you're still doing server side rendering of the initial react page, which doesn't work with what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In that case - you would need sticky sessions. If you are using Nginix, they have an appropriate configuration for that: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#enabling-session-persistence